# How to Use a TreeView as a Binding Source for Other Controls

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview

Consider a Tasks class:

```
TaskID
ParentID
Title
<several other properties>
Description
SubTasks <-- a collection of tasks
```

First I populate a hierarchy of Tasks called AllTasks and then load it into the TreeView by:

```
TaskTree.DataContext = AllTasks
```

That works fine.  Now I want to populate several other controls with the Task data when the user clicks on a Task from the TreeView.  I'll just consider the Description property as that is sufficient to illustrate the problem.

My TreeView is defined as follows:

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="TaskTree"
    SelectedValuePath="Task">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubTasks}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</TreeView>
```

The TextBox that should display the Description property of the Task selected by the user is defined by:

```
<DockPanel
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TaskTree}">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="txtDescription" 
        Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Discussion}"
</DockPanel>
```

Nothing is showing up in the TextBox.  I tried setting....

```
Text="{Binding Path=Discussion}"
```

... but that doesn't work either.  I've tried other combinations but to no avail.  What works?

Comment: You should implement a view model for that. See MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't select any `Task` in the outer `TreeView` named "TaskTree". Remove the outer one:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="TaskTree">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubTasks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

...and then try to bind to *its* `SelectedItem` property:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtDescription" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Discussion, ElementName=TaskTree}" />
```

Comment: Ya know, I stared at that XAML for HOURS and never noticed that I had a treeview inside another treeview.  Of course that's not correct.  How red is my face.  So all I had to do was delete the second "<treeView " and everything is working.  The "DataType" you suggested is apparently not needed.

Comment: I noticed that I just deleted in my code I missed to tell you he he